# What does it mean by building a website in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am sorry to have little knowledge in asp.net since its my beginning.

If I am not wrong, building a class library application creates files by compiling the code that are linked by some applications dynamically at run time i.e. it makes .ddl files of the class library application.

But, this time I am confused of building a site in asp.net. What it really does? Does it simply compiles the code or do more interesting things behind?

Any answers, links, comments or suggestions are heartily appreciated.

Comment: Thank you! all, for suggesting me to have general ideas while asking. I am sorry, I firstly was little unknown for this, and its you all help me. I will try my best in coming days. I have no idea and ways to edit this question. I do not mind closing this question. Thank you, again.

Answer (score 2):

In as.net, the code-behind (the `aspx.cs` files) are compiled into a dll, and the front-end (the `.aspx` file) acts as a 'link' - it is the file that is parsed ON the server and it returns a html page to the browser.

When you access the page in your browser, the server runs the `aspx` page (ON the server), the page communicates with the server-stored `.dll` (made from `aspx.cs`), thus generating the result `html` page which you'll see in your browser.

Comment: Would it be alright to say, each .cs file are converted to .dll files after building the application containing them?

Comment: Yes, that's the general idea. And then you have the aspx page, which gets the request from your browser and call the functions compiled into the .dll file. The .aspx gets the results and generates the html.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much the same. There are .aspx files and .cs files for every webpage you want to display. The code/logic is shared between both of this. Finally, on compile, this will be compiled to a .dll file.

The webserver which you will load it into will process the page requests and responses using this dll.

I would suggest you start looking at basic tutorials and start building a sample project and host it in your own machine IIS server. This will help you understand things in time.

Comment: You're wrong - the .aspx file isn't compiled. Try that yourself - change something in the .aspx on your IIS without rebuilding the binaries - you'll see the change in your browser, even though the .dll is the same. The .aspx page is only a bridge between the browser and server.

Comment: The .aspx, .ascx files are indeed dynamically compiled - but it allows very limited changes and meant for only structural changes only. Its too tightly to the designer files which take care of the runat="server" variables, and hence not meant as a separate logic unit.

Comment: there is an option to publish the website in a way that the aspx cannot be updated. In the publish dialog screen you can select the Configure link next to "Precompile during publishing" and there's an option in there for "Allow precompiled site to be updatable". If you uncheck it both the aspx and the .cs files are compiled into the dll, there will still be aspx pages pushed to the web server but the are just placeholders for the actual code that's in the dll